# "AppendChild" does not work inside a function?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

```
"use strict";

Object.prototype.$ = function( selector ) {
    var sel = selector;
    if ( typeof sel == "string" ) {
        var elem = document.querySelectorAll( sel );
        if ( elem.length == 1 ) return elem[0];
        else if ( elem.length > 1 ) return elem;
    } else
        throw new Error( "Can't find element!" );
}

Object.prototype.crElem = function( e ) {
    var name  = document.createElement( e.name );
    var place = $( e.place );
    if ( e.value == undefined ) {
        place.appendChild( name );
    } else if ( e.value ) {
        name.innerHTML = e.value;
        place.appendChild( name );
    }
}

crElem({
    name: "button",
    place: ".slide"
});
```

in the console comes out this error:
" Uncaught TypeError: place.appendChild is not a function "

Comment: By the way - why don't you use jQuery? It has this and more.

Comment: As an aside, why are you defining globals through `Object.prototype`? It may work, but it's certainly unorthodox.

Comment: You should be consistent. Either always return a single element, or always a collection of elements.

Comment: @Vilx-: Some people want to experiment with different ideas in a language, if for no other reason than to learn and understand pros and cons of different approaches. There's far less reason today to use a large library abstraction like jQuery than there was 5 years ago.

Comment: @squint - If that's his reason - sure, go ahead! This is great for understanding how things like jQuery (and Javascript, and HTML DOM) work. I just want to make sure that this isn't a misguided attempt at recreating something-like-jQuery for production purposes because the OP doesn't know about jQuery.

Comment: @squint - Also I disagree with not needing jQuery (or similar) today. Yes, browser compatibility is much less of a problem today, but that's not the only advantage jQuery provides. There's also a ton of utilities that make DOM manipulation A LOT easier. Yes, of course, you can do it all without jQuery - but with jQuery your code becomes a lot shorter and clearer.

Comment: @Vilx-: Why would that be misguided? Don't you believe in innovation? jQuery certainly isn't the library to end all libraries. I seriously doubt the OP doesn't know about jQuery, especially with the choice if `$`, which today is almost universally associated with jQuery.

Comment: @Vilx-: No, there's plenty of long, slow, unclear jQuery code out there. My code without jQuery is very short, clean and fast. There's very little reason to use it other than not knowing how to work without it.

Comment: @squint - I do believe in innovation. As I said, I only asked to make sure that this isn't a common beginner's mistake. Probably not, and that's all fine then. As for inefficient jQuery code - hmm, that's true, I can well imagine that. Well, as they say - with great power comes great responsibility. I can easily do both ways, but if I need to do a lot of DOM manipulations, I prefer the shorter style of jQuery. But I do see how it can be abused too, especially through ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$()` function returns an array, and then you try to call `.appendChild()` on that. Of course that won't work. You need to call it on a specific element, like `place[0].appendChild(name)`. Also, what will you do when `$()` returns several elements?